# Can Typescript have a case insensitive property match with Json?

Tags: json, typescript

Suppose I have this defined class in Typescript:

```
class Data{
   Dimension1: string;
   Dimension2: string;
   Metrics: Array<string>;
}
```

Is there a way i can declare an `Data` instance with json data below(properties in lower case)?

```
let json: Data = {
   "dimension1": "some dim",
   "dimension2": "some other dimes",
   "metrics": ["metric1", "metric2"]
}
```

Currently, the compiler would complain about Type's property are incompatible.

Comment: No. How would this be useful? JS key names are case sensitive.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Is there a way to do it yes. Should you do it no.

If you want to know however

```
let json: Data = <Data> {
   "dimension1": "some dim",
   "dimension2": "some other dimes",
   "metrics": ["metric1", "metric2"]
}
```

This will allow you to do what you want. Again i wouldn't do it.
If you want more options as in better options, you can let me know.
tick this answer if it's been useful.

Comment: But in this case when OP tries to access any capitalized property on `json` it will just result in `undefined`. How would this be useful? He might as well cast an empty object to `Data`

Comment: did you read my first line. Is there a way to do it yes. Should you do it no. That is the obvious reason as to not do it. I have even left a remark saying if you want more options as in better options let me know.

is there something more you would have liked me to do better. Does this not answer his question, tell him it's the wrong direction and offer further help in case he comes across something else. What more exactly should i do?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Typescript encourages to have camel case naming convention.

Comment: i answered the man question, advised him not to do it, and said if he needs more help let me know and i still get down votes?
this is text book case of you can't please everyone... :'(

Comment: I didn't vote, but you don't explain why not to do it or any downsides thereof (or even the fact that it probably wouldn't actually work as intended), so that may be a reason for a downvote.